# check if a matrix is symmetric and i get always the same result

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

I wrote a function that checks if the matrix is Symmetric . If it is, it will return 1, otherwise 0 .
It always returns zero. I tried to figure out where the mistake is, but everything seems correct to me.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 100

int Symmetrie (int matrix[][max]) {
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
      if(matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]) {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  int x;
  int  square_matrix[][max]={{1,2,3,4}
    ,{2,2,5,6}
    ,{3,5,3,7}
    ,{4,6,7,4}
  };
  x= Symmetrie(square_matrix[4][4]);
  if(x==1) {
    printf("1");
  } else {
    printf("0");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The function should return 1, but it returns zero. What am I missing?

Comment: you are passing only one number square_matrix[4][4]. Pass it as x=Symmetrie(square_matrix);

Comment: This shouldn't even *compile*, at least not without warnings. You're passing an `int` in place of an array, and you're accessing an array out of bounds. See the warnings at https://godbolt.org/z/MRSJWC. Also, why do you have `max` if you're hardcoding a 4x4 matrix?

Comment: regarding: `x= Symmetrie(square_matrix[4][4]);`  This is passing an element that one row and one element past the end of the actual matrix.  Suggest: `x= Symmetrie(square_matrix);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
x= Symmetrie(square_matrix[4][4]);
```

to this:

```
x = Symmetrie(square_matrix);
```

since your method expects the whole matrix as its parameter, not just an element.

`square_matrix[4][4]` is a single element of the matrix, i.e. the element in 5th row and 5th column. Of course this invokes *Undefined Behavior (UB)*, since your matrix has 4 rows.

More importantly, don't ignore the warnings generated. In GCC for example you would get something like this:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:24:32: warning: passing argument 1 of 'Symmetrie' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   24 |   x= Symmetrie(square_matrix[4][4]);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
      |                                |
      |                                int
prog.c:5:20: note: expected 'int (*)[100]' but argument is of type 'int'
    5 | int Symmetrie (int matrix[][max]) {
      |                ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

as you can see in the <kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/w8dURYQICnBg6L5E)</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Like others said, you should change:

```
x = Symmetrie(square_matrix[4][4]);
```

to this:

```
x = Symmetrie(square_matrix);
```

**But**, I would like to add and say that you could've found it very easily on your own by simply adding a small print.

A simple `printf("%d =?= %d", matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i])` right above the `if` would've shown you that the numbers are all gibberish.

**Or**, as @DanielH suggested, some compilers consider this as a warning, and you should not ignore these. For other compilers, adding `-Wall` as a compilation flag would have helped you catch this as well.

Comment: Also adding `-Wall` to the compilation line (you don't even need `-Wextra` or `-pedantic`, which I also recommend) would catch the error.

Comment: @DanielH, tnx, added

Comment: @DanielH, check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213396/2411320). There is no need for the warning flag...Although it's shouldn't hurt ofc ;)

Comment: @gsamaras Oh, you're right. I already had `-Wall` on when I compiled, and it did expose another warning (array access out of bounds), but I didn't try it without any warnings.

Comment: @DanielH with GCC 9 and `-Wall` I do not get a warning of out bounds, see the [Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vbZOGm1vj5JhfO5t).

Comment: @gsamaras I should have double-checked what I did. With [`-O3` in addition to `-Wall`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jrTzmGqtV7XW1Qid), I get a warning from GCC that element 4 of the outer array isn't initialized; it looks like GCC doesn't see that without optimization. In Clang, even without `-Wall`, [I instead get](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3gHwgVG4H8q11Vc0) the error I mentioned about 4 being out-of-bounds for the inner array.

Comment: Fascinating stuff @DanielH about the optimization flag, I got the same with O1, O2 too. In Clang you mean you got the *warning* about the out of bounds, not the error. :)

Comment: @gsamaras Yes, but I usually don't try to hard to distinguish them because in most cases I try to get warning-free builds. If you usually compile with `-Werror`, you don't always notice which word the compiler prints before it complains that you messed up.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your call

`x= Symmetrie(square_matrix[4][4]);`

to

`x= Symmetrie(&square_matrix[0][0]);`

Comment: mmm why the ampersand ? i don't understand  passing the adress of the elements

Comment: If you don't use the ampersand @Amerov, then it would similar to passing `square_matrix[4][4]`, as you did in your code, with the only difference of passing a different element. The method expects the whole matrix, not just an element!

Comment: @gsamaras so if I wirte it in that way Symmetrie(square_matrix[4][4])  as a parameter  here I'm passing just one element right?

Answer (score 1):

The below statement should be changed

`x= Symmetrie(square_matrix[4][4]);`

to

`x= Symmetrie(square_matrix);`

`square_matrix[4][4]` is just a single element at provided indexes. Pass the address instead.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already show the issue, but I'd like to point out that, using VLA syntax, it is possible to pass the actual size of the array to the function.
It's also worth noting that the loops can be limited to only one half of the "matrix":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_symmetric(size_t n, int matrix[n][n])
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
      //              ^^^^^
      if (matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

int main(void) {
  int  square_matrix[][4] = {
     {1,2,3,4}
    ,{2,2,5,6}
    ,{3,5,3,7}
    ,{4,6,7,4}
  };

  if( is_symmetric(4, square_matrix) ) {
    puts("The matrix is symmetric");
  } else {
    puts("The matrix is not symmetric");
  }
  return 0;
}
```